# Cordova contact plugin not working

Tags: angularjs, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

After calling this function I am getting the following error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'pickContact' of undefined"

```
$scope.pickContact = function() {
    navigator.contacts.pickContact(function(contact) {
        if(contact) {
            $scope.requestData.guestName = contact.displayName;
            if(contact.phoneNumbers && contact.phoneNumbers.length > 0) {
                $scope.requestData.phoneNo = contact.phoneNumbers[0].value;
            } else {
                $scope.requestData.phoneNo = null;
            }
            $scope.$apply();
        } else {
            $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Error!',
                template: 'Unable to get contact details'
            });
        }
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
        $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Error!',
            template: 'Unable to get contact details'
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Would need more info/code to really help here. A quick read of the error makes me think `navigator` is coming in OK, but `navigator.contacts` is not. Might be the plugin is not installed correctly - how did you install it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [$cordovaContacts](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/contacts/) plugin for get contacts and inject the dependency in your controller.

This plugin is available only on devices, not in the browser please do test on device.

For this plugin first you need to install [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/), this will support you for many more plugins and implementations.

Install plugin using following command,

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-contacts
```

Example :

```
        .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaContacts, $ionicPlatform) {
          $scope.addContact = function() {
            $cordovaContacts.save($scope.contactForm).then(function(result) {
              // Contact saved
            }, function(err) {
              // Contact error
            });
          };

          $scope.getAllContacts = function() {
            $cordovaContacts.find().then(function(allContacts) { //omitting parameter to .find() causes all contacts to be returned
              $scope.contacts = allContacts;
            }
          };
          $scope.findContactsBySearchTerm = function (searchTerm) {
            var opts = {                                           //search options
              filter : searchTerm,                                 // 'Bob'
              multiple: true,                                      // Yes, return any contact that matches criteria
              fields:  [ 'displayName', 'name' ]                   // These are the fields to search for 'bob'.
              desiredFields: [id];    //return fields.
            };

            if ($ionicPlatform.isAndroid()) {
              opts.hasPhoneNumber = true;         //hasPhoneNumber only works for android.
            };

            $cordovaContacts.find(opts).then(function (contactsFound) {
              $scope.contacts = contactsFound;
            };
          }

          $scope.pickContactUsingNativeUI = function () {
            $cordovaContacts.pickContact().then(function (contactPicked) {
              $scope.contact = contactPicked;
            }
          }

        });
```

Hope this will help you !!